# Python game timing

Tags: python, loops, time, coding-style, 2d-games

I'm trying to make a game in which I've got a bomb object that a has self detonate attribute called time.

when this time reaches 0 the bomb 'explodes' and disappears from the screen and then generates a new one in a different location.

I've managed to time my code by using a checkpoint before the loop and in the loop,

it does the job for the first bomb but not for the rest since each bomb object has a random explosion time and the time measured keeps going till infinity.
I need to relapse this time counter so i can detect when the different bombs will detonate.
heres my code so far

```
 start = time.time()                                        
 while True:                                                
    end = time.time()                                      
    bomb = board.bomb_list[0]                              
    update_board(board, gd, start, end, bomb.time_to_expo)
```

update_board:

```
if check_if_bomb_exp(start, end, bomb_timer):                 
     board.state[i][j] = '_'                                   
     game_display._buffer_draw_cell(i, j, 'white')             
     board.bomb_list = []                                      
     bomb = Bomb()                                             
     board.bomb_list.append(bomb)                              
     game_display._buffer_draw_cell(bomb.x_coor, bomb.y_coor,  
                               'red')
```

this part checks the times :

```
def check_if_bomb_exp(start_time, end_time, bomb_expo_time):   
    if bomb_expo_time == round(end_time - start_time):         
       return True                                            
    return False
```

Comment: We can't see full code, we can't run it (and we can't read in your mind) - I can only suggest to use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is doing.

Comment: maybe in bombs you should set explosion time as `bomb_expo_time = time.time() + random_delay` and later check `if bomb_expo_time >= time.time()`

Comment: because comparition `==` gives `True` or `False` so you can write `return (bomb_expo_time == round(end_time - start_time))`

Comment: you don't have to delete list - you could replace old bomb `board.bomb_list[0] = Bomb()` or in class `Bomb` you could create function which reset data - set new position and new explosio time - and then you could do `board.bomb_list[0].reset()`

Comment: I think main problem can that you use `==` but sometimes `round(end_time - start_time)` may gives not ideal result and it can skip moment when it is exaclty equal. You should rather use `<=`

Comment: BTW: pygame has `Clock` and it doesn't need `time.time()`

Answer (score 0):

I can't see full code and I can't run it so I guess.

---

I think problem can make `==`.

Every loop may take different time and sometimes it may skip moment when this is true

```
if bomb_expo_time == round(end_time - start_time):
```

and then bomb may exist forever.

It is safer to use `<=`. And it doesn't need `round()`

```
bomb_expo_time <= end_time - start_time
```

---

But frankly, it seems you set `how long bomb has to exist`

```
bomb_expo_time = random_delay
```

but I would rather set `time when bomb has to explode`

```
bomb_expo_time = time.time() + random_delay
```

and check

```
if bomb_expo_time <= time.time():
```

This also allow to show time to explosion (countdown)

```
countdown = bomb_expo_time - time.time()
```

---

**BTW:**

`PyGame` has `pygame.time.get_ticks()` which gives time (in milliseconds) since start of program - and it doesn't need `time.time()`

---

**EDIT:**

Minimal working example:

```
# https://www.pygame.org/docs/
#
# https://github.com/furas/python-examples/

import pygame
import random

# --- constants --- (PEP8: UPPER_CASE_NAMES)

SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600

FPS = 25

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED   = (255, 0, 0)

# --- classes --- (PEP8: CamelCaseNames)

class Bomb():

    def __init__(self):
        self.image = pygame.Surface((20, 20))
        self.image.fill(RED)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        # (re)set other values
        self.reset()
        
    def reset(self):
        self.rect.centerx = random.randint(10, SCREEN_WIDTH-10)
        self.rect.centery = random.randint(10, SCREEN_HEIGHT-10)
        self.full_delay = random.randint(1, 9) * 1000  # milliseconds 
        self.expo_time = pygame.time.get_ticks() + self.full_delay
        print('new time:', self.full_delay)
        
    def check(self, current_time):
        if self.expo_time <= current_time:
            print("explode")
            self.reset()
        self.countdown = self.expo_time - current_time
        
    def draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.image, self.rect)
        
        seconds = self.countdown / 1000
        
        text_image = font.render(f"{seconds:.01f}", True, WHITE)
        
        text_rect = text_image.get_rect()
        text_rect.centery = self.rect.centery
        text_rect.left = self.rect.right + 5

        surface.blit(text_image, text_rect)
        

# --- functions --- (PEP8: lower_case_names)

# empty

# --- main ---

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode( (SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT) )

all_bombs = [Bomb() for _ in range(5)]

font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 20)

# --- mainloop ---

running = True

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while running:

    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    
    # --- events ---
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False

    # --- changes/moves/updates ---

    for bomb in all_bombs:
        bomb.check(current_time )

    # --- draws ---

    screen.fill(BLACK)
    
    for bomb in all_bombs:
        bomb.draw(screen)
    
    pygame.display.flip()

    # --- FPS ---

    ms = clock.tick(FPS)
    
# --- end ---

pygame.quit()
```

[image]